# Unable to Scroll to UI object using Python-UIAutomator

Tags: android, python, android-uiautomator

I was wondering if I can scroll to an element on default android web browser where in the Web view is converted into a native XML tree.

I was trying to scroll to a UI element which in almost bottom of the page. I had used the following code fragment.

```
from uiautomator import device as d
from uiautomator import Device

d = Device('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
d(scrollable=True).scroll.to(text="XYZ")
```

But, I was not able to scroll to this object.

Any suggestions for alternate solutions on this problem?

Comment: Have you checked if the UI object element properties? It should say "scrollable" True. Then only you cane be able to scroll to that object.

Comment: Sure i will check that..